# Multivariate time-series with asyncronous data

Tags: time-series, bayesian, missing-data, sparse, linear-dynamical-system

I have quote observations for 9 FX rates, which I would like to analyze via multivariate dynamic linear model (e.g., Chapter 16 in West and Harrison [Bayesian Forecasting and Dynamic Models](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b98971) (1997).

In general, missing observations in a multivariate series can be handled like any other parameter in a Bayesian analysis: estimate both parameters and missing data given observed data and an inclusion indicator (e.g., Chapter 18 in Gelman et al. [Bayesian Data Analysis](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/book/) (2013).

But the above multivariate time series is extremely sparse (i.e., largely asynchronous): 97.7% of timestamps have only 1 variable (of a possible 9) observed, and another 2.1% of timestamps have only 2 variables observed. In no cases do I have more than 7 variables observed at the same time.

**Question:** Given the almost complete lack of synchronization in my data set, what options do I have to perform a multivariate analysis on this data set?

**What have I tried**

1. Synchronize the quotes by time aggregates (e.g., statistical summaries per second/minute);
2. Rely on the missing data model to work despite having almost no multivariate observations in the series.
3. The paper Peluso et al [A Bayesian High-Frequency Estimator of the Multivariate Covariance of Noisy and Asynchronous Returns](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2003492)  (2015) solves the same problem on a similarly asynchronous data set (~67-96% missing observations per timestamp), but seems to use a non-sequential Monte Carlo algorithm to do so. I'm keenly interested in a sequential approach given a) a lack of computing power at my disposal and the desire to run on a longer period than the above paper (e.g., 20 years vs. 11 months) and b) the desire to run the algorithm online vs. offline.

Comment: Could you give (more) complete references to the sources you cite?

Comment: Added links to both. Gelman is downloadable for non-commercial use.